# How to express regret about future events

Tags: grammar, negation, future

My coworker and I are both learning Japanese and working in Japan. While texting with a friend in Japanese to figure out when they should meet, my coworker wondered how to express: "The closing ceremony will probably not be over by then", while adding a sense of regret to not being able to meet by a certain time.

She recently learned the てしまう grammar point, and how it can be used to express regret, especially in the past tense (てしまった/ちゃった). She wondered if there was a way to use it about future events and/or in the negative form.

My Japanese is nowhere near good enough to figure this one out, so I wondered if anyone had any suggestion on how to convey this kind of meaning.

On the same topic, are there colloquial restrictions to てしまう? For example, I don't recall ever seeing this modifier used in the negative form. Also, I've seen it used in the non-past tense, but mostly to express "screw it, I'm gonna go ahead and...", like in 食べちゃう.

Sorry if this post is a bit messy or unclear, I am also confused! XD

Comment: As an English phrase, what does it mean *to regret about future events*? Maybe you can provide a concrete situation.

Comment: So your coworker is attending the closing ceremony?

Comment: @sundowner "Sadly, the ceremony will not be over by then, so I won't be free yet..." is what I meant.

Comment: @aguijonazo Yes she is.

Comment: You just need to express the meaning of "sadly" with an adverbial expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original meaning of the verb しまう is "to finish", and (-て)しまう as a subsidiary verb is like "to end up". Therefore, it cannot be used to express regret about something that didn't happen or won't happen. (-て)しまわなかった refers to the fact that an unfortunate event did not happen.

> 財布を落としてしまった。
> (Sadly,) I dropped my wallet.
>
> 財布を落としてしまわなかった。
> (Luckily,) I didn't end up dropping my wallet.

If a fact that "something didn't/won't happen" is unfortunate to someone, you need to use 残念ですが or 残念ながら instead.

> 残念ですが彼は来なかった。
> Unfortunately, he didn't come.
>
> 残念ながら財布を落とさなかった。
> Unfortunately (to you), I didn't drop my wallet.
> <sub>(The listener have said "I bet you'll lose your wallet!" before.)</sub>

But you can use it to refer to an unfortunate event that is likely to happen in the future.

> 明日財布を落としてしまうだろう。
> (Sadly,) I will likely drop my wallet tomorrow.
>
> 明日財布を落としてしまわなければいいのだが。
> I hope I won't drop my wallet tomorrow.

In your situation, you can say 残念ですがその時間には式が終わっていません.